# IPv6 - InetAddress.getAllByName returns inconsistent scope id

Tags: java, ipv6, inetaddress

I am new to IPv6.
I have a very simple code snippet as like below sample program to fetch and print the IP address of the host.

```
public class networkinterfacetest {
  public static void main(String...args) {
  String host="BGL-351L";   

    try {
        InetAddress[] a = InetAddress.getAllByName(host);
        for(InetAddress ip:a) {
        System.out.println("ip all:" + ip);
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The output has IPv4 and IPv6 address with scope id also.

I would like to know how this scope id is assigned. Because it is not consistent always. It keeps changing.

Yesterday when I ran the program I got the output as below with scope id "%2".

```
ip all:BGL-351L/10.10.64.86
ip all:BGL-351L/fe80:0:0:0:5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd%2
ip all:BGL-351L/fcff:3:10:64:5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd%2
```

And today If run the same program then I get "%3" as scope id.

```
ip all:BGL-351L/10.10.64.86
ip all:BGL-351L/fe80:0:0:0:5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd%3
ip all:BGL-351L/fcff:3:10:64:5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd%3
```

Can someone help me to understand how does this scope id is assigned.

Comment: Is this on Windows? If so, does the scope ID match the output of the scope ID found in "ipconfig"?

Comment: @JeremyVisser I am using linux. As you mentioned, it matches with "ip addr" command. I have updated that in my answer

Answer (score 1):

After digging up little bit, I have found out how this scope_id is fetched. This is the integer id assigned to the network interfaces available in the system. This interface id can be found using "ip addr" or "ip link" command.

I have a system where the ip addr output is as below.

```
[user@BGL-351L tch]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
  link/ether 08:11:96:09:04:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
  link/ether 5c:26:0a:77:e4:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 10.10.64.86/22 brd 10.10.67.255 scope global em1
  inet6 fcff:3:10:64:5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd/64 scope global dynamic 
   valid_lft 2591601sec preferred_lft 604401sec
  inet6 fe80::5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

In the same machine If I runthe above program, I have got the output as

```
ip all:BGL-351L/10.10.64.86
ip all:BGL-351L/fe80:0:0:0:5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd%3
ip all:BGL-351L/fcff:3:10:64:5e26:aff:fe77:e4fd%3
```

And in another machine the "ip addr" and program output are as below as

```
[user@BGL-341L]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
  inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
  link/ether 00:0c:29:64:61:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 10.10.68.24/22 brd 10.10.71.255 scope global eth0
  inet6 3002::20c:29ff:fe64:614a/64 scope global dynamic 
   valid_lft 2591981sec preferred_lft 604781sec
  inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe64:614a/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
  link/ether 9a:ee:72:78:fc:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
```

Program output:

```
ip all:BGL-341L/fe80:0:0:0:20c:29ff:fe64:614a%2
ip all:BGL-341L/3002:0:0:0:20c:29ff:fe64:614a%2
ip all:BGL-341L/10.10.68.24
```

So, In both the above cases, the id assigned to em1 or eth0 came as scope_id along with ipv6 address in java program output.

Answer (score 0):

From the java docs what I get is following based on which I can say each interface can have different scope_id values configured.

he IPv6-address is a literal IPv6 address as described above. The scope_id refers to an interface on the local system, and it can be specified in two ways.

As a numeric identifier. This must be a positive integer that identifies the particular interface and scope as understood by the system. Usually, the numeric values can be determined through administration tools on the system. **Each interface may have multiple values, one for each scope.** If the scope is unspecified, then the default value used is zero.

As a string. This must be the exact string that is returned by NetworkInterface.getName() for the particular interface in question. When an Inet6Address is created in this way, the numeric scope-id is determined at the time the object is created by querying the relevant NetworkInterface.

Note also, that the numeric scope_id can be retrieved from Inet6Address instances returned from the NetworkInterface class. This can be used to find out the current scope ids configured on the system.

So you get different values.